# How Read Users Of A Remote Linux Server with PHP ( Finger Protocol)

Tags: php

How can i read users of a remote linux server with PHP?
(like LDAP in windows)

If `finger` server has been runned on the remote linux server,**Now what?**

Comment: Read users? You want to read *me*? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Marcel I read he wants to enumerate the users.

Comment: The users on the system, the users in the database? I don't know LDAP, so I don't know what it does.

Comment: If **finger** service has been runned on the remote linux server,Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default service which allows to peek into active users. There is the `finger` service, but that's usually disabled nowadays.

You will have to set up a service yourself on that remote server. If it's not under your control, then you're out of luck finding out. Anyway, it's as simple as:

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: text/x-who");
   passthru("who");
```

For the logged in users. If you want to find out the existing users, then /etc/passwd would be to query. And if the server runs NFS or an actual directory service (which you didn't tell), then there might be other options.

Comment: If **finger** service has been runned on the remote linux server,Now what?

Comment: If so, try `finger @servername` to get a list.

Comment: I want to develope a site that users login with their **username and password on the remote server.**

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach then. Investigate if your case allows for utilizing a Linux LDAP or another directory server then. At the very least try Samba. -- If you just meant an authorization system that spans two **web**-servers, then OpenID is eventually what you want.

Comment: No OpenId is not what i want,I dont know about Samba.My friend did it with ldap in windows + ASP .NET and i want to implement it in linux + PHP.

Comment: Users have a username + password on an remote server and i want that they can login to my site with their username + password on remote server

Comment: Well you can use Samba with an LDAP user database. Otherwise Samba would just utilize the normal Unix user accounts (/etc/passwd). Can't give you more concrete advise however. (No expert with that.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will depend on how users are stored. If they're in an LDAP database, you will have to query LDAP, if they're in a database like MySQL, you'll have to query it etc. I don't think there's a standard way (e.g. through PAM modules, which abstract away these details for purposes of authentication) to query this kind of information.

In the most common (and simple) case, where the users are in `/etc/passwd`, you can connect to the server via [ssh](http://php.net/ssh2) and parse `/etc/passwd`, or read it directly if the server running PHP is the same from which you want to list the users.